# При копировании массива(матрицы) и в ходе модификации КОПИИ меняется исходный массив, передающийся функции, как аргумент

Tags: javascript, матрицы

Требовалось воссоздать принцип игры Сапер

```
matrix = [[true, false, false],
          [false, true, false],
          [false, false, false]]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function minesweeper(m) {
   let result = m.slice();
   for(let i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++){
        result[i][j] = m.slice(Math.max(i-1,0),i+2).map((row => row.slice(Math.max(j-1,0), j+2).reduce((s,el) =>
        s + el)).reduce((sum, n)=> sum + n,0) - m[i][j];
    }
}
return result;
}

minesweeper([[false,true,true,false], 
             [true,true,false,true], 
             [false,false,true,false]])

//Ожидаемый результат: [[3,3,3,2],
//                      [2,4,5,2],
//                      [2,3,2,2]].

//А по сути получаем: [[3,6,8,9],
//                     [10,28,53,71],
//                     [38,130,282,406]]
```

Проблема решается, если не копировать исходный массив, а создать новый...

```
function minesweeper(m) {  
   let result = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
      result.push([]);
      for(let j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++){
         result[i][j] = m.slice(Math.max(i-1,0),i+2).map(row => row.slice(Math.max(j-1,0), j+2).reduce((s,el) =>
         s + el)).reduce((sum, n)=> sum + n,0) - m[i][j];
      }
   }
return result;
}
```

Пожалуйста, объясните кто-нибудь, почему в процессе хождения интерпретатора по циклу меняется исходный массив тоже? Ведь я явно работаю с его копией...=(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы работаете с неполной копией. У вас массив массивов и вы создали копию только "внешнего" массива.

Надо скопировать и вложенные массивы тоже.

```js
function minesweeper(m) {
  let result = m.map(_m => _m.slice()); // копируем воженные массивы
  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    result.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
      result[i][j] = m.slice(Math.max(i - 1, 0), i + 2).map(row => row.slice(Math.max(j - 1, 0), j + 2).reduce((s, el) =>
        s + el)).reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0) - m[i][j];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
let a = [
  [false, true, true, false],
  [true, true, false, true],
  [false, false, true, false]
];

let b = minesweeper(a);

console.log(a, b);
```